# sqlite cordova javascript crashes

Tags: javascript, android, sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework

So I have a sqlite database which opens and executes well, however when I make sqlite functions at startup, the app freezes.

```
var init = (function() {
$scope.getAll();
})();
```

The problem is

```
var init = function() {
    $scope.Route = [];
    $scope.getAll = function() {
    db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB("transportation.db");
        var query = "SELECT agency_id, agency_phone FROM agency";
        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, []).then(function(res) {
            if(res.rows.length > 0) {
                for(var i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++) {
                    $scope.logerror = "Worked" + res.rows.item(i).agency_phone;
                    $scope.Route.push({id: res.rows.item(i).agency_id, agency_phone: res.rows.item(i).agency_phone})
                    $scope.stops = res.rows.item(i).agency_phone;
                    console.log("SELECTED -> " + res.rows.item(i).agency_phone);
                }
            } else {
                $scope.logerror = "No results found";
                console.log("No results found");
            }
        }, function (err) {
            $scope.logerror = "ERROR";
            console.error(err);
        });
  };
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you sure you have an existing instance (not null) of `$cordovaSQLite`? What error do you see in console? Have you tried putting console.logs around? say to check and log `db`? Also, you are checking for `res.rows.length`, I would put a log before that line too.

Comment: Yes I checked for rows.length with
    if(res.rows.length > 0) {

ng-click="getAll()" works but when I use the startup function it crashes.

Comment: So, I'd suspect the service sqlite isn't constructed yet, are you calling init after/inside deviceReady call? https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/events/events.deviceready.html